# ktor post request causes timeout on older Android devices (7.0)

Tags: android, ktor

I am using Ktor to send form data from an Android device using an http post request.I am using the latest version of Ktor (2.3.4).

On Android 7.0 devices the post request causes a timeout exception and on newer Android versions the post request just works fine.

I tried the post request using Postman and that also works fine.

Also I tried Android, CIO and OkHttp engines but that makes no difference.

Get and post request to other servers work just fine.
Postman also work when using a get request on the specific url, but on Android 7.0 it also causes a timeout exception.

Directly using HttpsURLConnection also causes a timeout exception for the specific url.

Using the logging provided by Ktor I see that the request is a valid one.

When I use C# to make a request to the specific url and Android 7.0 I don't get an timeout exception.

What could be the reason for the timeout problem on Android 7.0?

Comment: If the server is accessed via https it could be a TLS problem. Android 7 is pretty old and may have the necessary TLS version and/or ciphers disabled. Check the server what it supports/requires: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: I found out that the website only supports TLS 1.2 and above. In the emulator only a timeout can be seen and with debugging of a real Android device I see that there is a handshake error. How can I ensure that at least TLS 1.2 is chosen via kTor HttpClient that uses Android engine? Can I do the same with the client.submitForm method? @Robert

Comment: I have forced the connection to use TLS 1.2 but I still have problems with the connection in Android 7.0. With newer Android versions it does work. I read on the internet that the problem may also be due to certificates that Android 7.0 does not support.

Comment: Certificate problems never cause timeout exception. A timeout you can only get by networking problems. Or may be if there is a network component in between that performs TLS fingerprinting (like Cloudflare) and which rejects your device.